# CMake and Qt : directory for moc files / clean rules

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, cmake

I find CMake a little difficult to understand, and I currently have a problem with directories.

For the example, let's suppose that I have the following directory organisation :

```
project/
project/bin
project/obj
project/src
project/src/main.cpp
project/src/mainwindow.cpp
project/src/mainwindow.h
project/CMakeLists.txt
```

The project uses Qt 4.8 and CMake 2.8.8.
I want to do the following things :

- At the beginning of all compilation, all previous temporary files are cleaned (.o and .moc)
- All the .o and .moc are put in the obj directory
- The executable is put in bin

What is the simplest CMakeLists.txt to do that ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why would you want to clean all temporary files at the beginning? One of the big advantages of modern buildsystems is that they only rebuild that which has changed (and dependents)...

Comment: It is only for the development phase. My application is not so big, and I personally prefer to recompile everything each time. It's just a personal perference based on some problems I had during the first phase of development of previous programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is recommended to use out of source build where all the generated files are outside of the source folder. Is there any reason you are not doing that approach?

Comment: My source files are in project/src and I want generated files (.obj/.moc) to be in project/obj (outside of the source folder...), and the executable in project/bin